# Rust - Passing Trait Objects to Threads

Tags: rust, actix-web

I've been struggling with this for a while now and just going in circles, so I'm hoping someone can point out where I'm going wrong.

I'm playing with Actix Web, and setting up my first handlers - which is a simple Healthcheck of the system. So what I've got is:

- A `Healthcheck` trait defining a healthcheck
- A `HealthcheckHandler` struct that implements the `Handler` trait (This is an Actix Web concept) and contains a HashMap
- A function that builds an `App`  instance for the healthcheck routes (This is an Actix Web concept) by taking a `HashMap<String, &Healthcheck>`

​

When I try to build this I get errors that the trait "cannot be sent between threads safely".

I've tried with `&Healthcheck`, `Box<Healthcheck>`, `Box<Healthcheck + Send>` based on another answer on here, and even `Mutex<&Healthcheck>` all without luck, but all with subtly different errors. It all seems to be around needing to implement some combinations of Sync, Send and/or Clone, but I'm not sure how to get around that here.

Any pointers to what I should to fix this?

​

Actual example code:

```
pub trait Healthcheck {
    fn check(&self) -> Result<String, String>;
}
struct HealthcheckHandler {
    handlers: HashMap<String, Box<Healthcheck>>,
}
pub fn build_app(handlers: HashMap<String, Box<Healthcheck>>) -> App<()> {
    let handler = HealthcheckHandler {
        handlers: handlers,
    };

    App::new()
        .prefix("/health")
        .resource("", |r| {
            r.get().h(handler);
        })
}
pub fn start(settings: HashMap<String, String>) {
    let mut healthchecks: HashMap<String, Box<Healthcheck>> = HashMap::new();

    let server = server::new(|| { // <-- This is where the errors happen. This closure is used to spawn threads.
        vec![
            build_app(healthchecks).middleware(middleware::Logger::default())
        ]
    });
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. Try to reproduce your error in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here.

Comment: For example, `r.get().h(handler)` appears to be invalid for other reasons.

Comment: TL;DR the duplicates: `pub trait Healthcheck: Send + Sync` and `let mut handlers = HashMap::new(); let handler = Arc::new(HealthcheckHandler { handlers });`
`

Comment: In modern Rust, it's encouraged to use `dyn Trait` to clearly indicate that you are deliberately using a trait object. Here, it would be `Box<dyn Healthcheck>`.